# Dynamodb import data

Tags: mysql, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key, uuid, data-migration

I have a java microservice where I’m using MySql as database.

For multiple reasons I have to change sometimgs on it and I would like to change the MySql database to a Dynamodb database.

Currently on my sql db I already stored some data and I’m using an UUID string as primary key.

The question is, is it possible to migrate the data from MySql to Dynamo db with a possibility to reuse these already geberated primary keys?

I mean, my idea is to write a script in order to migrate the data… but is there any possibility or problems reusing the uuid primary keys?

Comment: It all depends on your access patterns, which you don’t describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamo is a NoSql db. That means it does not have tables and relationships. It has two keys, Partition and Sort, and the combination of these two make up a Primary Composite key (though you can just do a single Partition Key)

If you do not have a Sort Key assigned, then you *Cannot* re-use partition keys (uuid in your case) as it will overwrite (if using update) the existing item, or refuse to add (if using put_item)

In addition, because Dynamo is a noSQL, you do not have multiple tables. You have a single table. You cannot build multiple dynamo tables and make JOINS across them either - they are all separate entities

Not saying that moving data from an SQL to a Dynamo is impossible - but you have a lot of things to consider. One of the main things is how you access data. Since you cannot do JOINS and the like on a Dyanmo, you can't make any custom query you want whenever you want. The way your data is stored in dynamo determines how you would retrieve it - to expand, you want to store your data in a dynamo along *Access Patterns* - i.e. I always have data a, and I want to use it to get information, perhaps filtered along some operations against data b (such as > or <)

Simply having a Partition Key of a UUID is entirely possible, but it means that unless you choose to Scan the table (which touches every item, and is very expensive in time and potentially money if you have a lot of data) you MUST have that uuid in order to access the data that is associated with it.

SQL dbs and Dynamo sever two very different purposes in database storage. Dynamo is great for fast, quick reads where you know the starting data every time - Say you have a username, and you use that as your partition key, and then your sort keys are all the different data of the user: the avatar information, their access information, their stats on a game - you want to display all their games, you can query against user: games: and receive a list of data where each game is an entry.

SQLs are much better if you don't know what your access pattern is going to be. If you are not sure exactly what you may need to look up at any given time, SQL is far better, because of the ability to craft different queries at any point using JOINS and the like in order to manage data however you feel you might need it at that given point. Dynamo cannot do this - once you have your access patterns set, adding new ones is very annoying, and potentially costly, and trying to get data sets out of the table that it was never designed to be able to provide is always a difficult afair.

Comment: currently, on MySQL db I have just one table and I don't need to make joins.
In this table I'm storing devices data and I would like to reuse the same service to store different devices types (so with potentially different fields). I'll have a lot of devices that I have to store.. for this reason I'm thinking to use a noSQL db.
I use AWS and for this reason the idea is to use DynamoDB.
As I wrote, I already stored data so I need to move these data on my new noSQL db.. this is the point of my question

Comment: Then as long as you are fine. with looking up your data with your UUIDs every time, it can certainly work. But the first part still stays true - it will overwrite or refuse to write (depending on operation) if you re-use the same UUIDs

Comment: Sorry I just updated my comment in order to give you more details

Comment: I realize perhaps I misunderstood the last part of your question - there is no drawback to using UUIDs as a Partition Key - other than having to access only through that - ie you can query a particular UUID but doing a query say on "Any item with this value in this attribute" is not possible.

Comment: If all you need to do is query by the UUID then this is definitely a fine approach and will be very quick. If you need to perform different queries (ie: get all devices of type x ) then you will want to seek another approach: Use PK as the Device Type perhaps and Sort Key as your UUID. Then you can get all devices of type X, or get device x: uuid for a specific. It depends entirely on your access patterns and how you plan to get the data.

Comment: Let me to give you a more bit detail. I have to store the device with a specific primary key (currently I used UUID) and I have to link it to a specific user id (one other UUID). The additional fields are not relevant for this service (for example device OS, app version, etc). I don't need to query the db using these fields. The only queries that I need are, eg, "get all user devices", "get/delete/update a device info given a device key". Just this. I don't need other specific queries.

Comment: Then you would best be set with the following access schema: Partionkey: USER#[UUID] SortKey: DEVICE#[UUID]. Store each uuid as well in their own attributes (UserID, DeviceId) to make seeing them without having to parse the str possible. THen set up a Global Secondary Index that flips your PK and SK (so your Sort Key becomes your Primary in the GSI and your Primary becomes your sort).

You can then either query for all devices of a user: Query PK = USER#[UUID] or against the GSI with query GSI (pk) = DEVICE#UUID to get a specific device.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand that it's probably better to study the Dynamodb indexes usages..  :D I'll back in case I'll discover some others doubts..

Comment: I have one additional doubt. Suppose that I need to have one additional field, something like "context_id". For each device I'll have this context_id and I would like to include this field into my queries: eg. get all user devices by user_id and contentx_id.
What's the better solution to include this field? Is it enough to create a dedicated index for it (which type of index?)

Comment: There isn't a good one. An index would be a second query (and you have very little reason to ever do a local). If you are only querying by that value you could do a GSI on it if you choose.  You could also concat that with your sort key if that makes sense and then do a #begins with# query of your context Id. This is where dynamo starts to get weird - multiple access patterns for the same data can be difficult to solve